# D/Dlang: Lua interface, any way to force users to have no access to intermediate objects?

Tags: lua, d

Status: Sort of solved. Switching Lua.Ref (close equivalent to LuaD LuaObject) to struct as suggested in answer has solved most issues related to freeing references, and I changed back to similar mechanism LuaD uses. More about this in the end.

---

In one of my project, I am working with Lua interface. I have mainly borrowed the ideas from LuaD. The mechanism in LuaD uses lua_ref & lua_unref to be able to move lua table/function references in D space, but this causes heavy problems because the calls to destructors and their order is not guaranteed. LuaD usually segfaults at least at the program exit.

Because it seems that LuaD is not maintained anymore, I decided to write my own interface for my purposes. My Lua interface class is here: https://github.com/mkoskim/games/blob/master/engine/util/lua.d

Usage examples can be found here:
https://github.com/mkoskim/games/blob/master/demo/luasketch/luademo.d

And in case you need, the Lua script used by the example is here:
https://github.com/mkoskim/games/blob/master/demo/luasketch/data/test.lua

The interface works like this:

- Lua.opIndex pushes global table and index key to stack, and return Top object. For example, `lua["math"]` pushes _G and "math" to stack.
- Further accesses go through Top object. Top.opIndex goes deeper in the table hierarchy. Other methods (call, get, set) are "final" methods, which perform an operation with the table and key at the top of the stack, and clean the stack afterwards.

---

Close everything works fine, except this mechanism has nasty quirk/bug that I have no idea how to solve it. If you don't call any of those "final" methods, Top will leave table and key to the stack:

```
lua["math"]["abs"].call(-1); // Works. Final method (call) called.
lua["math"]["abs"];          // table ref & key left to stack :(
```

What I know for sure, is that playing with Top() destructor does not work, as it is not called immediately when object is not referenced anymore.

NOTE: If there is some sort of operator to be called when object is accessed as rvalue, I could replace call(), set() and get() methods with operator overloads.

Questions:

1. Is there any way to prevent users to write such expressions (getting Top object without calling any of "final" methods)? I really don't want users to write e.g. `luafunc = lua["math"]["abs"]` and then later try to call it, because it won't work at all. Not without starting to play with lua_ref & lua_unref and start fighting with same issues that LuaD has.
2. Is there any kind of opAccess operator overloading, that is, overloading what happens when object is used as rvalue? That is, expression "a = b" -> "a.opAssign(b.opAccess)"? opCast does not work, it is called only with explicit casts.

---

Any other suggestions? I internally feel that I am looking solution from wrong direction. I feel that the problem reside in the realm of metaprogramming: I am trying to "scope" things at expression level, which I feel is not that suitable for classes and objects.

So far, I have tried to preserve the LuaD look'n'feel at interface user's side, but I think that if I could change the interface to something like following, I could get it working:

```
lua.call(["math", "abs"], 1);          // call lua.math.abs(2)
lua.get(["table", "x", "y", "z"], 2);  // lua table.x.y.z = 2
...
```

Syntactically that would ensure that reference to lua object fetched by indexing is finally used for something in the expression, and the stack would be cleaned.

---

**UPDATE:** Like said, changing Lua.Ref to struct solved problems related to dereferencing, and I am again using reference mechanism similar to LuaD. I personally feel that this mechanism suits the LuaD-style syntax I am using, too, and it can be quite a challenge to make the syntax working correctly with other mechanisms. I am still open to hear if someone has ideas to make it work.

The system I sketched to replace references (to tackle the problem with objects holding references living longer than lua sandbox) would probably need different kind of interface, something similar I sketched above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have an issue when people do

```
auto math_abs = lua["math"]["abs"];

math_abs.call(1);
math_abs.call(3);
```

This will double pop.

Make `Top` a struct that holds the stack index of what they are referencing. That way you can use its known scoping and destruction behavior to your advantage. Make sure you handle `this(this)` correctly as well.

Only pop in the destructor when the value is the actual top value. You can use a bitset in `LuaInterface` to track which stack positions are in use and put the values in it using `lua_replace` if you are worried about excessive stack use.

Comment: Thanks! I changed Top to struct, I wasn't aware that its destructor gets called at the end of statement. Yes, I would like to prevent people to store Top objects anywhere, and then try to use it later - it will def lead to problems. Your suggestion does not yet entirely resolve those issues, but it is definitely a big step forward!

Comment: I updated code in repo. Simple usage errors are now handled. One example of errorneous use which don't get caught: `a = lua["funca"]; a.call(); b=lua["funcb"]; a.call()` which calls funcb instead of funca.

Comment: I marked your answer right, although I made some other modifications. Anyways, your suggestion to make Top as struct was very helpful! I am describing the current solution as an answer.